# What is the name of this kind of character illustration?

Tags: interface-design, illustration, character-design

[image]

I have seen lots of UI designer nowadays including this kind of illustration i want to know the name of this style so that i can also learn and try this in my designs.

Comment: Hello Yashu, welcome to GDSE, we're glad to have you! You can read the introduction in [help] on how to improve your question and [edit] it accordingly. Feel free to contribute to the site by asking more questions or answering questions of others.

Comment: Dear God, what happened to her head?!?

Comment: https://dribbble.com/galshir you ll find good examples here!

Answer (score 1):

I bet you will not find any established name for the distorted perspective and dimensions of the human character in your image. And if someone had given a name for it, it's useless until you had built your own between-the-ears model what it has and how to draw everything.

So: Find some good works and try to copy them (for yourself only!). Decide what are the essentials. Then try to apply the findings to your own characters.

You will succeed if you are able to step up from copying.

BTW company named Tubik Studio seems to use plenty of this style human characters. Maybe their designer - probably Yaroslava Yatsuba - gives some hints if you ask.

**ADD: User Danielillo wrote in his comment** that Tubik Studio has given a generous explanation and they call it Flat Design.

Comment: Actually their web has all the explanation about the illustration, they call it Flat Design: https://tubikstudio.com/how-to-create-original-flat-illustrations-designers-tips/

Comment: But "flat design" means **nothing**. Flat design is about the flatness of the color. And this is not even flat. It has texture. The implied shadow will make it for some "flat design 2.0", some would call it "flat design 2.0 with texture". but again it says NOTHING about the proportions.

Answer (score 0):

Iconic illustration.

-or-

Disproportionate illustration.

-or-

Vector minimal illustration.

-and-

**Experiment more than look to the others!**

Find your own style and make people asking how to call it!

Best!